# Gaussian integration by parts?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do we integrate this expression

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-ax^2}  \,dx$$

Using integration by parts? Whenever I attempt it the two terms just cancel and I'm left with 0, which is not what the answer is supposed to be, and no online source seems to solve this using integration by parts.

Comment: Where is $dx$?..

Comment: You can reduce it to $\int e^{-ax^2}\,dx$.

Comment: You do not need $\text{IBP}$. For any $a>0$
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2 e^{-ax^2}\,dx\stackrel{\text{symmetry}}{=}2\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2 e^{-ax^2}\,dx\stackrel{x\mapsto \sqrt{z}}{=}\int_{0}^{+\infty}z^{1/2} e^{-az}\,dz =\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{a^{3/2}}.$$

Comment: You need a factor of $x$, but just one, in order to do integration by substitution. So you include one in the $dv$ and put the other in the $u$. In the end you still need to deal with $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2} dx$. As Jack already pointed out, the other way to proceed is to change variables to convert it to a Gamma function integral, though unless you know something about the Gamma function, you're actually better off where you're starting if you want an explicit solution.

Comment: The function is even hence it equal $$2\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2e^{-ax^2} dx$$ Try some online resources for gamma function and Gaussian integrals

Comment: @Manthanein That modification is not useful at all.

Comment: @Ian I don't think that because Jack D'Aurizio already used it and posted answer as a comment

Comment: @Manthanein Converting to a semi-infinite problem makes it harder to do the polar coordinates trick to do the final integration.

Comment: @Ian Yeah you are also correct about that.  Sorry or the trouble :-)

Comment: @Ian no it does not, just have angle go $[0,\pi/2]$ to scan over the first quadrant

Answer (score 3):

Hint

Consider
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-ax^2}  \,dx=-\frac 1 {2a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(-2axe^{-ax^2})  \,dx$$
Integrate by part

Answer (score 1):

How about just differentiating under the integral sign?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^{2}}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

Differentiate both sides w.r.t. $a$ to get:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}e^{-ax^{2}}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \color{red}x \cdot x e^{-ax^2} {\rm d} x = \Bigg[x \int x e^{-ax^2} {\rm d} x - \int \color{red} 1 \cdot \left( \int x e^{-ax^2} {\rm d} x \right) \Bigg]_{-\infty}^{\infty}  $$

Comment: To quote Manthanein, where is $dx$?

Comment: Wait a minute what is that. $$\int 1\cdot\int xe^{-ax^2}$$

Comment: @Manthanein See the edit. In by parts, we have to differentiate a term too.

Answer (score 0):

$a>0$,

$\begin{align}J&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-ax^2}  \,dx\\
&=2\int_{0}^\infty x^2e^{-ax^2}  \,dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{a}\Big[x\text{e}^{-ax^2}\Big]_0^{\infty}+\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}  \,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}  \,dx
\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $y=\sqrt{a}x$,

$\begin{align}J&=\frac{1}{a^{\frac{3}{2}}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-y^2}  \,dy\\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{a^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}}\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to establish that$$\int\limits_0^{\infty}dx\, e^{-ax^2}\color{red}{=\frac 12\sqrt{\frac {\pi}{a}}}$$This can be done by first squaring the expression, using Fubini’s theorem, then changing to polar coordinates$$\begin{align*}I^2(a) & =\int\limits_0^{\infty}\int\limits_0^{\infty}dx\, dy\, e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}\\ & =\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\int\limits_0^{\infty}dr\, d\theta\, re^{-ar^2}=\frac {\pi}{4a}\end{align*}$$Since replacing $x$ with $-x$ generates the same result, it’s natural to see that$$J(a)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}dx\, e^{-ax^2}\color{blue}{=\sqrt{\frac {\pi}a}}$$Now, differentiate with respect to $a$ gives$$J’(a)=-\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}dx\, x^2e^{-a x^2}=-\frac {\sqrt{\pi}}{2a^{3/2}}$$So$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\, x^2e^{-ax^2}\color{brown}{=\frac 1{2a}\sqrt{\frac {\pi}a}}$$